# QTreeView crashing with no apparent reason

Tags: pyqt, python-3.4, qt4.8

I introduced a treeview in the GUI of the program I'm making and since it crashes when I attempt to change its model once it has been set.

The course of action is:

> - load the file using a file dialogue
> - clearing the models on the interface objects (tables and treeview). The first time the treeview is not affected since there is no model in
>     it.
> - Populate the treeview model.
> - other stuff not related to the issue.

The problematic functions are;
The file loading procedure:

```
def open_file(self):
        """
        Open a file
        :return:
        """
        print("actionOpen_file_click")
        # declare the dialog
        # file_dialog = QtGui.QFileDialog(self)
        # declare the allowed file types
        files_types = "Excel 97 (*.xls);;Excel (*.xlsx);;DigSILENT (*.dgs);;MATPOWER (*.m)"
        # call dialog to select the file
        filename, type_selected = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNameAndFilter(self, 'Open file',
                                                                       self.project_directory, files_types)

        if len(filename) > 0:
            self.project_directory = os.path.dirname(filename)
            print(filename)
            self.circuit = Circuit(filename, True)

            # set data structures list model
            self.ui.dataStructuresListView.setModel(self.available_data_structures_listModel)
            # set the first index
            index = self.available_data_structures_listModel.index(0, 0, QtCore.QModelIndex())
            self.ui.dataStructuresListView.setCurrentIndex(index)

            # clean
            self.clean_GUI()

            # load table
            self.display_objects_table()

            # draw graph
            self.ui.gridPlot.setTitle(os.path.basename(filename))
            self.re_plot()

            # show times
            if self.circuit.time_series is not None:
                if self.circuit.time_series.is_ready():
                    self.set_time_comboboxes()

            # tree view at the results
            self.set_results_treeview_structure()

            # populate editors
            self.populate_editors_defaults()
```

The treeview model assignation:

```
def set_results_treeview_structure(self):
        """
        Sets the results treeview data structure
        @return:
        """

        # self.ui.results_treeView.setSelectionBehavior(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        # model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Elements'])
        self.ui.results_treeView.setModel(model)
        # self.ui.results_treeView.setUniformRowHeights(True)

        def pass_to_QStandardItem_list(list_):
            res = list()
            for elm in list_:
                elm1 = QtGui.QStandardItem(elm)
                elm1.setEditable(False)
                res.append(elm1)
            return res

        bus_results = pass_to_QStandardItem_list(['Voltages (p.u.)', 'Voltages (kV)'])
        per_bus_results = pass_to_QStandardItem_list(['Voltage (p.u.) series', 'Voltage (kV) series',
                                                      'Active power (MW)', 'Reactive power (MVar)',
                                                      'Active and reactive power (MW, MVar)', 'Aparent power (MVA)',
                                                      'S-V curve', 'Q-V curve'])

        branches_results = pass_to_QStandardItem_list(['Loading (%)', 'Current (p.u.)',
                                                       'Current (kA)', 'Losses (MVA)'])
        per_branch_results = pass_to_QStandardItem_list(['Loading (%) series', 'Current (p.u.) series',
                                                         'Current (kA) series', 'Losses (MVA) series'])

        generator_results = pass_to_QStandardItem_list(['Reactive power (p.u.)', 'Reactive power (MVar)'])
        per_generator_results = pass_to_QStandardItem_list(['Reactive power (p.u.) series',
                                                            'Reactive power (MVar) series'])

        self.family_results_per_family = dict()

        # nodes
        buses = QtGui.QStandardItem('Buses')
        buses.setEditable(False)
        buses.appendRows(bus_results)
        self.family_results_per_family[0] = len(bus_results)
        names = self.circuit.bus_names
        for name in names:
            bus = QtGui.QStandardItem(name)
            bus.appendRows(per_bus_results)
            bus.setEditable(False)
            buses.appendRow(bus)

        # branches
        branches = QtGui.QStandardItem('Branches')
        branches.setEditable(False)
        branches.appendRows(branches_results)
        self.family_results_per_family[1] = len(branches_results)
        names = self.circuit.branch_names
        for name in names:
            branch = QtGui.QStandardItem(name)
            branch.appendRows(per_branch_results)
            branch.setEditable(False)
            branches.appendRow(branch)

        # generators
        generators = QtGui.QStandardItem('Generators')
        generators.setEditable(False)
        generators.appendRows(generator_results)
        self.family_results_per_family[2] = len(generator_results)
        names = self.circuit.gen_names
        for name in names:
            gen = QtGui.QStandardItem(name)
            gen.appendRows(per_generator_results)
            gen.setEditable(False)
            generators.appendRow(gen)

        model.appendRow(buses)
        model.appendRow(branches)
        model.appendRow(generators)
```

And the GUI "cleaning":

```
def clean_GUI(self):
        """
        Initializes the comboboxes and tables
        Returns:

        """
        self.ui.tableView.setModel(None)
        if self.ui.results_treeView.model() is not None:
            self.ui.results_treeView.model().clear()

        self.ui.profile_time_selection_comboBox.clear()
        self.ui.results_time_selection_comboBox.clear()
        self.ui.gridPlot.clear()
```

The complete code can be seen [here](https://github.com/SanPen/GridCal/blob/master/main_gui.py)

I have seen that this behavior is usually triggered by calls outside the GUI thread by I don think this is the case.
I'd appreciate if someone could point out the problem. Again the complate code for test is [here](https://github.com/SanPen/GridCal/blob/master/main_gui.py).

Comment: Don't link to Github or other external sites. Put all your code here on SO to ensure that future readers can read the version that actually caused the issue. Reading the snippets that you gave us is unlikely to reveal the problem, so the chances of getting a good answer from us are slim. That's why you should make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can just copy-paste-run. Remove all unrelated code until the smallest program that demonstrates the bug remains. There is a good chance that you will find the sollution yourself that way.

Comment: In my experience most crashes can be avoided by explicitly disconnecting the signals of an object before it is deleted. [This page](http://enki-editor.org/2014/08/23/Pyqt_mem_mgmt.html) is where I read about it.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem in a separated project but it behaved like it should. Also I get no warning or error message, just a clean crash. Furthermore, when debugging, at the code the line that calls `model.clean()` the model is accessible and I can read its items, so I have no clue of what is the problem. Also everything executes on the main thread.

Comment: If you can produce something that doesn't demonstrate the problem, then add more of the functionality back in until it does cause the problem. That should pinpoint the issue and either you, or someone here will be able to solve the problem. Otherwise this question is not going to be helpful to anyone else visiting the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this in my case has been the following:

The `QStandardItemModel()` variable called model in the code was turned into a class global variable `self.tree_model`

When I want to replace the `treeview` object model, I delete the global `tree_model` with `del self.tree_model`

Then I re-create the global model with `self.tree_model = QStandardItemModel()`

This way the TreeView object model is effectively replaced without crashing...